# What does she say?

Tags: перевод

Can anyone help me in telling what the woman says in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1PJNK5aBNk&t=0m15s) cartoon? It is only few words before: "крокодиль играи"

Comment: Hello astabada. You didn't provide any effort for your request and even if we don't have a policy for this particular question, we highly discourage questions that don't provide that effort.

Comment: @Alenanno, actually I believe we have policy for such questions - it is about translating from Russian, which is off-topic.

Comment: @shabunc Technically this is not a translation request. The OP is asking to transcribe spoken language. See [this Meta question](http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/q/278/71)

Comment: In my defense, I tried to understand, and have listened to the video so many times... but I have an hard time understanding the lady in particular, apart from obvious, simple sentences like "крокодиль играи".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

— Молодец, старик! Не оставил друга! А ну-ка, подвинься... Крокодил, играй!

— Good for you, old fellow! Did not leave a friend! C'mon, move over ... Crocodile, play!

Answer (score 0):

She gives Gena the Crocodile a garmon (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garmon) and commands, "Крокодил, играй!" which means, "Crocodile, play [it]!"

Comment: Ops, I was asking what does she say *before* "Крокодил, играй!" :-)